# SQL Developer doesn't give output with Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I turned on server output using 'SET SERVEROUTPUT ON'.
also opened 'dbms output' tab and connected to user. ( in sql developer > view > dbms output > plus sign > connect )
I have installed oracle 10g.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Testing output');
end;
/
```

I'm getting only 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.' as ouput.

( It's duplicate question, but as i'm newbie and not have enough credits to comment on that question. so, ... )

Comment: What do you get issuing `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE` rather than `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`?

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of SQL Developer doesn't support 10g.

It mostly works, but one of the things that doesn't is polling for DMBS_OUTPUT.

You need convince someone it's worth the time to upgrade that system.

Comment: its the only option, i guess.

Comment: @ZalaJaydipsinh - It is not the only option. You can look for an older version of SQL Developer, one that supports Oracle 10. You can look for other interfaces; or you can work in SQL\*Plus. With that said, there are many other reasons to upgrade; the ability to use the latest version of SQL Developer is a good reason, but it probably won't make the top-five or top-ten list.

Comment: Any effort spent trying to get dbms output working should PALE in comparison to securing your system by upgrading it to a supported platform/version